# Which of the following statements about UFDs and PIDs are true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following statements are true?

1. A  subring of  a unique  factorization domain (UFD) is  a  UFD
2. A  subring of a principal ideal domain(PID)  is a PID
3. A subring of a Euclidean domain is a Euclidean domain

I think statement $2$ is incorrect, since  $\mathbb{R}[x]$  is a PID  but $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not.

I am not able to find counterexamples for the other two statements.

Comment: The ring $\Bbb{C}$ is an UFD, but several subrings, like $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are not. So also 1 and 3 are not true in general - see also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617872/is-any-subring-of-a-euclidean-domain-a-unique-factorization-domain).

Comment: Every domain $R$ is canonically realized as subring of some field, called the *field of fractions* of $R$. $\operatorname{Frac}R$ can be described as the set of equivalence classes of $R\times (R\setminus \{0\})$ by the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff da-cb=0$. Out of similarity with $\Bbb Q$, the equivalence classes are indicated with $\frac ab:=[(a,b)]_\sim$. The operations are then $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ and $\frac ab\cdot\frac cd=\frac{ac}{bd}$ and the map $R\to\operatorname{Frac}R$ that sends $x\to\frac x1$ realizes $R$ as a subring.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Why not add the final details and write that as an answer?